# What is framing and why does it need processed?

Tags: bug

I'm currently trying to upload some photos and I'm getting a site error.  The alert box is stating that "for security reasons, framing is not allowed, click to ok to remove" (wording more or less).  However, when I click on the "ok" button it does a redirect that is hitting an error page at the moment.

So what is the framing business all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is very confusing.

I believe the issue is that the image you're trying to upload is too large.

Imgur (which SE uses for images) has a 2MB file size limit and the error it returns uses frames. Or maybe it's only for animated gifs over 2MB?

More info here:
["For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames." on Imgur upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a web technology called *framing*, which I think plants one page inside an empty placeholder page. To the user it is invisible, but you can introduce (hidden) code in there to e.g. prevent the page being loaded from another site.

I just mention this in passing, I've no idea whether or why SE would use it. But maybe its something to do with that?

Or could it maybe be a technology used by your browser to facilitate e.g. private browsing? (I don't know how private browsing works, I'm just thinking out loud.)

Comment: After a few attempts of uploading photos thinking that I had something messed up in them, I did switch out for my programming hat.  Given that I was getting an alert box instead of the expected response for photos too large, there seems to be issues with with the handling code.  I'm thinking that the image uploads are done with a hidden iframe, choking hard, and the response is redirecting to a different website.